# Position one svg element relative to point

Tags: svg

Input: a point coordinates in SVG, and inner SVG element (just code)
Output: this inner SVG element placed so that the point is the center of this element.

Any Idea how to accomplish it?

In css and HTML elements I may use for example `tranform: translate(-50%, -%50)` to shift element relative to its own size relative to its position, or use some other centering techniques. But with SVG don't know the working way.

Found useful `text-anchor` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/text-anchor attribute for horizontal text positioning relative to some point.

Comment: I guess, find the width/height of the object (maybe from getBBox out of the display area or precalculated), and adjust the x,y cx,cy or whatever to the center point minus half of the width&height or something ?

Comment: Well But I don't have this element in dom, I thought to make without need of such calculations with a need of insertion in to the DOM.